# Static context is null after been set

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, nunit, rider

This .Net Core 3.1 (NUnit 3) test works under Visual Studio 2019.

But as soon I use JetBrains Rider the test fails because the static property (`DataA`) returns `null` in mostly all contexts.

Has some a idea what goes wrong and how to solve this issue?

```
public static class ClassA
{
    public static string DataA { get; set; }
    public static string DataB { get; set; }
    
    public static void SetAppConfig(string appSettingsPfad)
    {
        IList<JProperty> appSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(appSettingsPfad).Select(j => (JProperty)j).ToList();

        var appKonfiguration = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (JProperty property in appSettings)
        {
            var appKonfigurationProperty = appKonfiguration.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            var value = ((JValue)property.Value).Value;

            if (appKonfigurationProperty != null)
                appKonfigurationProperty.SetValue(null, Convert.ChangeType(value, appKonfigurationProperty.PropertyType));
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class DummyTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestA()
    {
        LoadAppConfig();
        
        // DataA returns null here
        Console.WriteLine(ClassA.DataA);
        
        new BusinessLogicClass.DoSomething();
        // [...]
    }
    
    private void LoadAppConfig() {
        // [...]
        string appSettings = File.ReadAllText(jsonConfigFiles.Single());
        ClassA.SetAppConfig(appSettings);
        
        // here it works and a result is the proper string
        Console.WriteLine(ClassA.DataA);
        // [...]
    }
}

public class BusinessLogicClass {
    
    public void DoSomething() {
        // DataA returns null here
        Console.WriteLine(ClassA.DataA);
        // [...]
    }
}
```

*(I have simplfied this code to the bare minimum, the orginal code would run into a Exception after a null check)*

Comment: Please remove the config related code from the [mcve] since it is not `DataA`. Can you simplify the [mcve] further (i.e. not read from config file)? Make it is as short and simple as possible.

Comment: @jdweng How does OP question is related to TLS?

Comment: Not get a response from _what_ @jdweng? I mean, sure, it might be related - but if so how did you *work that out*?

Comment: @mjwills without this code part the way the data is set would not be clear since the involved reflection could also involved in the underling issue...

Comment: @JanS. The point of you creating a [mcve] is for you to **narrow down** where the problem is. That is what _minimal_ is. That is your job. Maybe it is related - but you will work out whether it is relevant or not when you simplify it down. The key is for you to give us as small as possible a sample that reproduces the issue. Your code, as is, is not minimal - since there are too many moving parts. Keep taking things away until the test starts working. Then focus on the last change you made - since it is where the problem lies.

Comment: Another way to think of it is this - either you have a reflection bug, or a JSON parsing bug, or a "I call a setter and then the value is lost" bug. A [mcve] will help us work out which of the three it is - and get you the solution faster.

Comment: As my code comments express the values are read properly from json and the values are set to the given properties once ... the properties return null later on ....

Comment: How to reduce the code more if I don't know which is the root cause of the issue ... maybe I would remove a relevant element ...

Comment: `How to reduce the code more if I don't know which is the root cause of the issue ... maybe I would remove a relevant element` That is one of the benefits of making a [mcve]. The mere act of putting one together often helps you discover the problem. There is a bug there now. You remove a piece. The bug is gone. **Clearly the last thing you changed caused the bug**. Now you know where to focus.